# Rotating legend item labels in QGIS Layout Manger?

Tags: qgis, labeling, legend, rotate

I want to create horizontal legend in QGIS (v 3.8.0). Is it possible to rotate legend item labels in Layout Manager?

[image: capture]

Comment: Cut the legend with screen capturer and rotate picture. This picture you can import to print layout.

Comment: No. Use multiple single-item legends side-by-side, or delete the text from the legend and enter it manually into a text box.

Answer (score 1):

You could rotate the WHOLE legend by -90 degrees, via the setting under the "Rotation" group:

[image]

That looks like the result you're chasing...

Comment: Thanks ndawson. That's actually what I did - rotated whole legend by -270 degrees and altered spacing and size of items, but that rotated labels as well. Will try differed methods, maybe splitting into columns...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @csk. This is what I came up with after rotating legend by -90deg, editing spacing and size of items, deleting label text and entering it manually

[image]